# Spotify-API for iOS available for public distribution?

Tags: spotify

I was just wondering if Spotify ever plan to make their iOS SDK available for public distribution? As for today it's in beta 3 and only available for private use.

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because its not related to programming, and would fit much better on Spotify's developer site (https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/).

Comment: I agree. Next time I'll just use the comment at the developer site for Spotify.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course - once the SDK is out of beta it'll be free to use for publicly distributed apps.

Comment: It's still in beta. Any advice on how to use it in an iOS app that will be publicly distributed?